Flutter TextStyle TextDecoration.lineThought Error
In flutter I got this widget
 Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: RichText(
                        maxLines: 1,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        text: TextSpan(
                            children: [
                          TextSpan(
                              text: "$price€  ", style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
                          startingPrice != price
                              ? TextSpan(
                                  text: "$startingPrice€",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize:19,
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,))
                              : const TextSpan()
                        ]),
                      )),

and the result I get is this one

I tried different combinations of fontSizes and the line thought looks like it's moving up and down just a bit, but never in the center which is the desirable place.
The same up and down movement is happening if I add a height property in the Container and increase/decrease it.
Any thoughts?

I can reproduce your result. I don't know if this is intentional behavior or not from flutter.

Use WidgetSpan which will give you access to use alignment. But it works when fontsize are x and 2x. It is better to use Row to achieve required UI.
 RichText(
          text: const TextSpan(
            children: <InlineSpan>[
              TextSpan(
                text: '200',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              WidgetSpan(
                alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
                child: Text(
                  '30',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

